# HtaccessRules to redirect my website

Tags: .htaccess

Hi can anyone of you suggest me on how to redirect my page http://testsite.com/about.php to http://testsite.com/about/ by using htaccess rewrite rules.Without using any query string in the page url i need to rewrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want a redirect but a rewrite. A redirect means informing the client to requery for the redirected url, whereas rewriting means telling the server to interpret an url as being some other url.
and you dont' want to rewrite about.php to /about/ but the other way around. You want your users to type in /about/ and that url to be handled by /about.php

and this is done by:

```
RewriteEngine on # this line enables rewrite
RewriteRule /about/$ /about.php
RewriteRule /about$ /about.php
```

I'm not sure if both of the above are actually needed or just one (I don't have access to an apache right now to test)

In the slight chance that you actually do want a redirect as you wrote, use this free redirect generator: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/ (it's easier than learning all the quirks of the conditions to match up)
in your case that will be:

```
Redirect 301 /about.php /about/
```

Comment: ok thanks about it. i have used the following lines of code to achieve it RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php.